# How can I tell I'm using an XP server vs. an XP workstation?

Tags: windows-xp

This should be obvious, but I can't seem to locate or think of anything that would indicate clearly whether I'm using an XP server or a workstation.

Thanks for the help.
Mark

Comment: Do you mean XP Professional vs. XP Home? (or Media Center, or Tablet, etc..)

Comment: This question is a result of trying to install XP disk mirroring. In some of the instructions, some people were saying that it's not possible on XP workstation edition. Maybe I just read it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy way to tell:

Press the Windows Button Key and at the same time press PAUSE (or Break)

A box will appear, with all sorts of useful information and at the top, what version of XP you are using, its Service Pack level and a few bits of Hardware information.

This works on most MS products (there are lots of short cuts like that)

Answer (score 5):

XP is not a server OS.  It mainly comes in Workstation, Home, and Media Center versions.

MSKB on determining XP version:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;310104

Comment: This gives you some really interesting information about the version. I don't think I've ever seen or needed such detail info. I wonder when I would need it, if ever.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on 'My Computer' and click Properties, it will tell  you right at the top the version you are running.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as Windows XP server, so it's doubtful you're using that. The server equivalent of XP is Server 2003

If in doubt, bring up the start menu, that will tell you what you're running

I don't have an XP machine to get an example at the moment, but if you hit the start menu, select run and enter `winver' that application will also tell you what it is that you're running

There appears to be a [semi-useful list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions) of versions of Windows on Wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

Just press Ctrl-Alt-Del, it tells you the Windows version there:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose someone could be using an XP machine as a web server or a file server or even a print server.  Look at what processes are running.  Do you see any server-ish processes such as Apache?  What ports are open?  Is file and print sharing enabled?

Also, look at user accounts and shares.  Browse around on the machine a bit.  There should be some obvious tipoffs.

Comment: You're over-thinking my question. :-)

Comment: I must STILL be overthinking it...I read the question and the answers and think I have missed something....but it looks like you found your answer...